# Update field based on null or not null value of field in another table

Tags: database, ms-access

NOTE: Microsoft Access being used

I'm currently working on a database system in Access for loan management of resources.

I currently have a resource table (which holds all the resources info) which has a quantity field. I need it so when someone takes out a loan of a certain resource (identified using ResourceID as PK) than Quantity is decremented by 1 and when someone returns the book it increments by 1 (DateOut field and DateReturned field possibly used?).

I just need to find a way in Microsoft Access to be able to implement this but can't come up with anything.

Comment: Can you provide a query you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you use VBA then your form will need to fire an event, such as AfterUpdate.

Another option you have is to use [Data Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200).  You can set up a Data Macro to "trigger" after the table is updated.  In this trigger you would check if the conditions have been met, and then if they have, you could update the value.    If you need to increment / decrement in another record or table, then you'll need to use the AfterUpdate event.  If, however, the increment/decrement field is in the same record you can use the BeforeChange event, and it becomes much easier to implement.

Of course, you should also consider your design.  Perhaps the way the table is designed currently can be improved upon, given the new requirement.   If you simply maintaining a running "on hand" / "on loan" count for each book (each book having its own record), then what will you do when the counts don't balance?  Maybe you want to have another table to keep track of Who signed it out / returned it and when.

Comment: Thanks! I currently use Access but I think you may have given me help in solving it!

Comment: My answer *was* for Microsoft Access.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm dumb and didn't think of Data Macros as being Macros from Access as never heard them put as Data Macros. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Data Macros are like Triggers on SQL Databases.  In Access 2010 and later you can find the Data Macros by going into the Table design view adding them via the ribbon.

Comment: Okay, will give it a go!